# Unable to load class 'com.sun.istack.FinalArrayList'

Tags: android, gradle

I can't build on AndroidStudio

I already update Android Studio, JDK, reboot and nothing.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/istack/FinalArrayList
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:246)
    at com.android.repository.impl.meta.SchemaModuleUtil.getContext(SchemaModuleUtil.java:104)
    at com.android.repository.impl.meta.SchemaModuleUtil.setupUnmarshaller(SchemaModuleUtil.java:211)
    at com.android.repository.impl.meta.SchemaModuleUtil.unmarshal(SchemaModuleUtil.java:194)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.parsePackage(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:305)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.parsePackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:159)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.getPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:124)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl$LoadTask.run(RepoManagerImpl.java:518)
    at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager$DummyProgressRunner.runSyncWithProgress(RepoManager.java:397)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl.load(RepoManagerImpl.java:365)
    at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager.loadSynchronously(RepoManager.java:290)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler$RepoConfig.createRepoManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:726)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getSdkManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:296)
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.init(DefaultSdkLoader.java:386)
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getSdkInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:367)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:178)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.java:885)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:702)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:652)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:648)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.istack.FinalArrayList
    ... 116 more
```

Comment: Please create a [mre], and read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/6296561

Comment: Hi, where you able to find what could cause you this error?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Maven, try this dependency : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.10

Otherwise, add this jar to the classpath:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.10/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.10.jar